# MongoDB - Expected element name to be 'DateTime', not 'Ticks'. error

Tags: mongodb, datetime

I've exported a mongoDB collection and import it to a different database/server.

When i try to get the data from this collection i had "Expected element name to be 'DateTime', not 'Ticks'." error.

After spending lots of hours I've noticed that there was an order error on CreatedDate field.

It must be like that;

```
"CreatedDate" : {
   "DateTime" : ISODate("2015-04-02T16:11:50.901Z"),
   "Ticks" : NumberLong(635635879109017711)
},
```

But in some records it is like that;

```
"CreatedDate" : {
   "Ticks" : NumberLong(635635879109017711),
   "DateTime" : ISODate("2015-04-02T16:11:50.901Z")
},
```

"Ticks" and "DateTime" values are not in correct order and it throws an error.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I'm not sure the order matters here, since objects are *unordered collections of properties* (in JavaScript at least). I believe the issue must be caused by something else.

Comment: I've solved the problem. I've updated the c# mongo driver and it is resolved.

Comment: Great! Then, answer you own question and mark this answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the c# mongo driver solved my problem.